# Ошибка при изменении ip адреса

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Запускаю код, который должен изменить мой ip адрес:

```
import requests

proxy = {
    'http': 'http://165.22.81.30:36435',
    'https': 'https://165.22.81.30:36435'
}

r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxy)
print(r)
```

Но возникает ошибка:

```
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='165.22.81.30', port=36435): Max retries exceeded with url: http://httpbin.org/ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)))
```

IP и порт брал с сайта:
https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/?type=h&anon=4#list

Скажите, как исправить ошибку? 
Нашел в интернете, что нужно в словаре в значении дописать 
**'http' : 'http://165.22.81.30:36435'**,
а не просто 
**'http' : '165.22.81.30:36435'**,
но безрезультатно.

Comment: поправил ваш код, запустил... print(r) >>> <Response [200]>, r.json() >>> {'origin': '185.220.101.213'}... странно, конечно, что не 165.22.81.30, но ошибки нет

Comment: @Jack_oS так может он ваш ip и вывел

Comment: нет, не мой )) вот снова запустил: r.json() >>> {'origin': '45.154.35.218'} похоже на какой-то транзит

Comment: попробуйте другой прокси?  этот при запросе на https://ifconfig.me/all.json тоже ругается requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ifconfig.me', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url после 15 сек молчания даже с verify=False в параметрах запроса, и на https://hidemy.name/ua/proxy-checker/ не чекинится

Comment: @Jack_oS прокси беру с сайта, с другими происходит аналогично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Google Colab` всё работает, выдаёт ответ:

```
{'origin': '185.220.101.213'}
```

Причём, работает в обоих вариантах - и если просто `IP:PORT` задать у прокси, и если `http://` впереди написать - без разницы.

Без указания `proxies` выдаёт другой адрес в результате и гораздо быстрее это делает, так что настройки прокси реально работают.

Возможно, у вас недоступен адрес этого прокси, либо вас на нём уже забанили.

Comment: но должен работать в яндекс браузере, а в яндексе не робит

Comment: забанить не могли на этом сайте http://httpbin.org/ip